# Add rows to datatable if distinct

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, loops, datatable, distinct

I have a datatable which I keep cleaning and I put in values into it. So once in the execution time the data in the table looks like this

1211 A B C

1212 D E F

I have a datatable  dt_new and add both these rows.(because first column is distinct).
Some times the data ends up like this

1213 I  J K

1213 L M N

In this case I want to NOT add any of the row to my dt_new.(because first column is same for both rows)
How do i do this? Looks simple but i am ending up with varied results. I am checking by iterating the table and checking for first column but not getting result. 
If you need more info, please ask.Thanks

```
    For Each drTempRow As DataRow In dtTemp.Rows
                Dim intCounter As Integer = 0
                Dim intCounterEqual As Integer = 0
                For Each drInnerRow As DataRow In dtTemp.Rows
                    If drTempRow("CustomerID") <> drInnerRow("CustomerID") Then
                        intCounter += 1

                    Else
                        intCounterEqual += 1
                    End If
                Next
                If intCounterEqual = 1 AndAlso intCounter <> dtTemp.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                    Dim drNewRow As DataRow = dt_new.NewRow()
                    drNewRow.ItemArray = drTempRow.ItemArray
                    dt_new.Rows.Add(drNewRow)
                End If
            Next
```

Comment: Should each loop be iterating through the same collection of rows like you have it? They both iterate through `dtTemp.Rows` meaning `drTempRow("CustomerID") <> drInnerRow("CustomerID")` would always fail at least once.

Comment: @BubbleHearth. Yes. dtTemp is the table with rows. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you be comparing what is in `dtTemp` with what is in `dt_new`? That way if something in `dtTemp` already exists in `dt_new` it doesn't get added?

Comment: @BubbleHearth. No I want to check in that mini table dtTemp itself. That datatable is result of a join on address table. So if i have a customer with 2 addresses then it shows up 2 results, but infact it is one customer.

Comment: Ok, so then if there are two results in `dtTemp`, you only want to add one of them to `dt_new`? `dt_new` is a distinct list of customers, disregarding addresses? Or you are only adding customers that have one record in `dtTemp` to `dt_new`?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it this way without a nested loop:

*Remember: You must sort your `dtTemp` by `CustomerID` first, before use this code.*

```
Dim dt_new As DataTable = dtTemp.Clone()
Dim previousId As String = ""

For Each drTempRow As DataRow In dtTemp.Rows
    If Not drTempRow("CustomerID").ToString().Equals(previousId) Then
        dt_new.ImportRow(drTempRow)
    End If

    previousId = drTempRow("CustomerID").ToString()
Next
```